# Calling ASMX webservice from JQuery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I'm currently trying to get the response from an asmx service and use it in an autocomplete textbox

Here the code i'm currently using:

```
    $(function () {

            $("#<%=txtParentCat.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
                selectFirst: true,
                source:  Magelia.WebStore.Admin.Scripts.Services.AutoCompleteServices.GetCategoriesFull,
                extraParams: { contains: $('#<%=txtParentCat.ClientID %>').val(), storeId: '<%=this.Page.UnitOfWorkContext.StoreId.ToString() %>' },
                minLength: 0,
                delay: 0,
                autoFocus: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                parse: function (data) {
                    var rows = new Array();
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        rows[i] = { data: data[i], value: data[i], result: data[i] };
                    }
                    return rows;
                },
                formatItem: function (row) {
                    return row;
                },

                autofill: true,

                highlight: false,
                multiple: true,
                multipleSeparator: ";"
                ,
                response: function (event1, ui) {

                    var input = $('#<%=txtParentCat.ClientID %>');
                input.on('keydown', function (event) {
                    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

                    if (key == 8 || key == 46)
                        select = false;
                    else
                        select = true;
                });

                if (select == true && ui.content.length > 0) {
                    var $userVal = this.value;
                    var $newVal = ui.content[0].value;

                    if ($userVal != "") {
                        var n = $newVal.toLowerCase().indexOf($userVal.toLowerCase());

                        if (n == 0)
                            n = n + $userVal.length;

                        if (n != -1) {
                            $("#<%=txtParentCat.ClientID %>").val($newVal);
                            setSelectionRange($("#<%=txtParentCat.ClientID %>").get(0), n, $newVal.length);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

I keep getting a 500 internal error which i think must be because i'm sending the parameters needed to call the webservice the wrong way.

Here the parameters required to call the service:
Magelia.WebStore.Admin.Scripts.Services.AutoCompleteServices.GetCategoriesFull(contains,storeId,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext)

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance :)